# Windows Phone 7 Creating video streams

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, video

Hi i am creating a project in windows phone 7 that will capture videos and transport it to some other device. Here is my code so far.

```
// Initialize the camera if it exists on the device.
        if (videoCaptureDevice != null)
        {
            captureSource = new CaptureSource();

            fileSink = new FileSink();
            // Create the VideoBrush for the viewfinder.
            videoRecorderBrush = new VideoBrush();
            CompositeTransform transform = new CompositeTransform();
            transform.CenterX = 0.5;
            transform.CenterY = 0.5;
            transform.Rotation = 90;
            videoRecorderBrush.RelativeTransform = transform;

            videoRecorderBrush.SetSource(captureSource);

            // Display the viewfinder image on the rectangle.
            viewfinderRectangle.Fill = videoRecorderBrush;

            // Start video capture and display it on the viewfinder.
            captureSource.Start();
            // Set the button state and the message.

        }
```

What i want is to save the the video that was captured to some kind of buffer,so that i can send it and the other device can see that video (Video Call). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bsically you can go for this sample fro msdn

the [voip sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/ChatterBox-VoIP-sample-app-b1e63b8b)

for a normal description of how to make application here's a link in silverlight

you can mapp at least some code and understanding from here ..

[video call silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65190/Your-First-Step-to-the-Silverlight-Voice-Video-Cha)